# Cron : Why are my cron scripts not running even though cron is running

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, cron, postgresql

I have a 4 scripts to transfer database from one server to other for testing purpose. These scripts execute automatically in the night. When I call the scripts manually, I get no error, but without running them manually, I cannot see any data being transferred.

Server 1 :

```
ps -ef | grep cron
root      2350     1  0 Apr23 ?        00:00:26 /usr/sbin/cron
root     14293  9533  0 10:52 pts/4    00:00:00 grep cron
```

Server 2 :

```
ps -ef | grep cron
root     11269  8661  0 10:52 pts/1    00:00:00 grep cron
root     21726     1  0 Jan30 ?        00:00:31 /usr/sbin/cron
```

Server 1

```
crontab -e
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 3 * * * /home/deploy/scripts/clearzip.sh
19 2 * * * /media/attachment/send_db.sh
```

send_db.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
pg_dump -C "DB_NAME" | bzip2 | sshpass -v ssh user@server2 "bunzip2 | psql "DB_NAME""
pg_dump -C "DB2" | bzip2 | sshpass -v ssh user@server2 "bunzip2 | psql "DB2""
```

Server2 :

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
12 2 * * * ./home/postgres/stop_services.sh
17 2 * * * ./home/postgres/dropdb.sh
55 5 * * * ./home/postgres/start_services.sh
```

stop_services.sh :

```
#! /bin/bash
echo > >(tee -i /home/deploy/logfile.txt)
sh /home/deploy/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh stop
killall java
killall screen
```

dropdb.sh

```
su -c "psql -c 'drop database "DB1";'" -s /bin/sh postgres
su -c "psql -c 'create database "DB1";'" -s /bin/sh postgres
su -c "psql -c 'drop database "DB2";'" -s /bin/sh postgres
su -c "psql -c 'create database "DB2";'" -s /bin/sh postgres
```

What might I be doing wrong? Any ideas?

*Update*

Errors in log file

```
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
/home/postgres/start_services.sh: line 5: service: command not found
/home/postgres/start_services.sh: line 6: service: command not found
```

Comment: cron should send you a mail if any error occured, have you check root's mail ? `/var/log/messages` ?

Comment: @Archemar : On both servers, no mail for root...

Comment: Don't use `su` in crontab - use that users crontab instead `sudo contrab -u postgres -e` or even better use `/etc/cron.d/<cronfile>` where you can specify the user before the command ie `12 2 * * * root /home/postgres/stop_services.sh` (also, why do you have a . in front of `/home` ?)

Comment: @MichaelDaffin : Those dots might be a problem. Before the scripts were in /root, then I moved them, forgot about those dots. The script is executed as root, should I still use sudo under that condition? Thanks

Comment: You should also use passwordless ssh keys instead of `sshpass` - my guess is that the scripts are blocking/chocking on expecting stdin to be a terminal, which is not true for cron jobs.

Comment: @MichaelDaffin : Yes, the ssh keys have no password, we are using public key authentication with empty passwords. Also, when I exexute the command manually with sshpass, it goes smoothly.

Comment: Have you checked whether the scripts are actually running? Edit your crontab and add `2>>/tmp/logFile` or similar to each command in your crontab. Then check if `/tmp/logFile` is created and tell us if there are any errors. Your pg_dump script will probably fail, for instance, because you're not using the full path to it. And your second crontab will fail because you're using `./home` instead of `/home`.

Comment: @terdon : The scripts are not failing when called manually. I have removed the dot after michaels comment. Added the 2>>/tmp/logfile, will wait till tomorrow to see if it worked.

Comment: Don't wait for tomorrow! Change them so they run every minute, and just check what happens. What I suggested is a way to debug the issue, not solve it. And yes, of course the scripts run manually, that's because your user has the command in the `$PATH`. Check the logfile as I told you and edit your question with the results.

Comment: Try using absolute paths in your scripts. And is `/media/attachment` mounted with `exec` option?

Comment: @terdon : I get 2 different errors in /tmp/logfile. I have added them in the bottom of main post. Can you please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems:

1. You are running things that need root privilege but are running them as a regular user.
2. You are using command names without their full PATH and therefore, the session opened by cron doesn't know where to find them.

To fix 1., don't use `crontab -e` and instead edit `/etc/crontab` or, even simpler, run `sudo crontab -e` to add it to root's crontab. Then, edit your `dropdb.sh` and remove the `su` (the script will now be launched by root, so no need for `su`).

To fix 2, the simplest approach would be to define the PATH in the crontab. It should look like this:

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
# m h  dom mon dow   command
12 2 * * * ./home/postgres/stop_services.sh
17 2 * * * ./home/postgres/dropdb.sh
55 5 * * * ./home/postgres/start_services.sh
```

Alternatively, edit your scripts and make sure they all use absolute paths (so `/usr/sbin/service` instead of `service`).